# Spring Data Neo4j - Null Response

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am trying to run a custom CQL using Spring Data Neo4j. I believe I have most of the code working but I am getting a **null** value. Below is the code I have so far;

**.properties:**

```
spring.neo4j.uri=bolt://localhost:9486
spring.neo4j.authentication.username=neo4j
spring.neo4j.authentication.password=password
logging.level.org.springframework.data.neo4j=DEBUG
```

**pom.xml**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>

<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
```

**Entity class**

```
@Node("Job")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class Children {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    private ArrayList<Children> children;
    private Text text;


    @Getter
    @Setter
    public static class Text {
        public String name;
    }
}
```

**Repository**

```
import com.horsefly.analyticsapi.model.node4j.Children;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.Neo4jRepository;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface ChildrenRepository extends Neo4jRepository<Children, Long> {

    @Query("MATCH (j0:Job {Position: 'supervisor', jobCountryCode:'uk'}) WHERE j0.id=1 RETURN {text:{name: j0.Position}, children: []} AS Tree")
    Children cqlTest();

}
```

**Component**

```
@Component
public class Neo4jBuilder {

    @Autowired
    private ChildrenRepository childrenRepository;

    public String getChildren() {

        return childrenRepository.cqlTest();

    }
}
```

I am trying to log the query that I am sending via the property in .properties but I am not seeing anything interesting.

```
2023-03-16 15:29:51.980 DEBUG 17480 --- [           main] o.s.d.n.r.c.StartupLogger                : Bootstrapping reactive Neo4j repositories based on SDN v6.1.6 with Spring Data Commons v2.5.6 and Neo4j Driver v4.2.7-b09866e7932eff1844519ce1a75c0cfdc3c782b3.
2023-03-16 15:29:52.005 DEBUG 17480 --- [           main] o.s.d.n.r.c.StartupLogger                : Bootstrapping imperative Neo4j repositories based on SDN v6.1.6 with Spring Data Commons v2.5.6 and Neo4j Driver v4.2.7-b09866e7932eff1844519ce1a75c0cfdc3c782b3.
```

Also, I used both dependencies individually and did not see any difference.

The "*cqlTest*" function returns null. However, when I run the same query on the browser, I am seeing the below result.

[image]

I have a matching node (Job) and fields in the Children object but not sure why I am getting a null. Any help would be great. I tried **String** as the return type on the cqlTest() but no luck there as well
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Spring Data Neo4j repositories, like all Spring Data repositories, operate entity-centric. This means it will happily map anything that will result in a proper instance of your domain classes (the ones annotated with `NodeEntity`). For this it needs for example the id and labels.
You are returning a map with loose values and SDN does not really know what to do with this.

There are a few options:

1. You could use the `Neo4jClient` for this use-case.
   It has a fluent API to execute the query, bind parameters and map the result with a custom mapper. https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#neo4j-client
   Also, it participates in the Spring transactions as the repository does.
2. You could write your own repository extension to encapsulate (1) within the repository. This might be the way to go if you are using more functionality of the `ChildrenRepository`. https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations
3. You could define DTOs for the data collection. But they are a little bit limited and won't support the map structure. You would have to return the values flatten. Here is a repository that should give you an impression: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-neo4j/blob/a41fbad5ab2976db3b5bc2e2d0018afab6920678/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/neo4j/integration/lite/SomeDomainRepository.java#L28

Comment: Thank you. Do I have to use NodeEntity? Can I achieve the same thing with Node annotation? I have tried Neo4jClient and got the proper response for a simple query. I then tried a more complex query but It did not return the results that I had on the browser. I also checked the custom repo usage but in my case, I am using Query on the interface function and I don't have anything to fill in the Impl's function so why the ChildrenRepository is not enough by itself? It can be like any other CrudRepository with the Query on top of the function definition.

Comment: Also, can you please clarify what you mean by "loose"? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say `@Node` (the NodeEntity annotation is from another OGM framework). The data you are returning does not represent mappable data for SDN in the way it expects a node to get mapped. That's why I said _loose_ in this context. So returning the map with some values and (empty list) of children nodes does not say anything to SDN. In the documentation is also a reference for custom queries and what SDN expects to work properly: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#custom-queries